# how to fix redirected you too many times?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I have `Drupal 6` site. www.abc.com

This production site is loading fine. But while accessing the dev site i.e., `dev.abc.com`

I am getting the below error

```
The dev.abc.com page isn’t working

dev.abc.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I tried different browser but still same error,

How do I get rid of these error & access my site.

Things tried by me:-

1. Uploaded all the fresh files
2. Pointed to different database
3. Clearing cookies & Ignite window

Thanks.

Comment: Debug the webserver. There is no way around it. There needs to be a reason why you always get redirected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the site's main .htaccess file's `rewrite_base` directive is set correctly. Also if there are redirects within the site's vhost container make sure those are not conflict with the settings in .htaccess.

> **Note**: Drupal 6 no longer receives community support.  While there are
>   LTS services available it is strongly recommended that all Drupal 6
>   sites be migrated to Drupal 7 or Drupal 8.